# Sqlite order by time closest to now

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My sqlite raw query needs to be able to sort dates based on how close they are to now. What is wrong with my sqlite statement?

```
public Cursor GetFirstTime(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor nextTime = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select  * from timemanager_table where " + seconds + " >= dateday ORDER BY dateday Limit 5",null);
    return  nextTime;
}
```

Comment: Is `dateday` in milliseconds? Why did you assign a variable named "seconds" to milliseconds?

Comment: So if table has rows that are 10 and 5 minutes in the past, and 3 and 7 minutes into the future, the "sort dates based on how close they are to **now**" should sort them: 3 (future), 5 (past), 7 (future), 10 (past)? If not, then you just want a normal sort, and "close to now" has no meaning.

Comment: This Question is not clear. Are you dealing with past, present, and future moments? If so, please address the comment by Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dateday` is seconds, then you can do this entirely in SQL (you don't need a Java calendar).

This query says find first 5 elements that are before now.

```
SELECT * 
FROM timemanager_table 
WHERE dateday <= strftime('%s', 'now') 
ORDER BY dateday DESC
LIMIT 5
```

In other words, see [SQLite Date & Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

If `dateday` is in some other format (like `YYYY-MM-DD`), you will need to `strftime` it, probably.

---

If you need to sort based on "close to now", then you need to do some date subtraction.

```
SELECT *, dateday - strftime('%s', 'now') AS time_diff
FROM timemanager_table 
ORDER BY time_diff DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Which will add an additional column with negative values for those in the past, 0 for now, and positive values for those in the future.